# Python run exe with subprocess.run and arguments

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to use Sumatra pdf to send a pdf to the label printer using python script. Unfortunately, it looks like the double quote ('-print-settings "landscape,1,5x"') specifying the number of copies and orientation is not passed on correctly.

```
import subprocess
arg = ['SumatraPDF.exe','-print-to-default','-silent','-exit-on-print','-print-settings "landscape,1,5x"','qrcode_and_date.pdf']
subprocess.run(arg, shell=True)
```

How this command should be formatted properly to achieve the desired result.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: normally you should put it as two separated values `'-print-settings',  '"landscape,1,5x"'` but if you run it with `shell=True` then you have to put all as one string without `[]` like `run('SumatraPDF.exe -print-to-default ... -print-settings "landscape,1,5x" qrcode_and_date.pdf', shell=True)`

Comment: if you have problem to split string with command into list then use [shlex.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you should put it as two separated elements on list `'-print-settings'` and `'"landscape,1,5x"'`

```
import subprocess

arg = [
    'SumatraPDF.exe',
    '-print-to-default',
    '-silent',
    '-exit-on-print',
    '-print-settings',
    '"landscape,1,5x"',
    'qrcode_and_date.pdf'
]

subprocess.run(arg)
```

But if you use `shell=True` then you should put all as one string

```
import subprocess

arg = 'SumatraPDF.exe -print-to-default -silent -exit-on-print -print-settings "landscape,1,5x" qrcode_and_date.pdf'

subprocess.run(arg, shell=True)
```

At least on Linux you have to use it this way.

---

**BTW:**

You could simply use `split()` for this

```
import subprocess

arg = 'SumatraPDF.exe -print-to-default -silent -exit-on-print -print-settings "landscape,1,5x" qrcode_and_date.pdf'

arg = arg.split()

subprocess.run(arg)  # without `shell=True`
```

but if you would have spaces inside `"landscape, 1, 5x"` then it would create wrong list with three elements `'"landscape', '1', '5x"'` so [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) suggests to use [shlex.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split)

```
import subprocess
import shlex

arg = 'SumatraPDF.exe -print-to-default -silent -exit-on-print -print-settings "landscape,1,5x" qrcode_and_date.pdf'

arg = shlex.split(arg)

subprocess.run(arg)  # without `shell=True`
```